# PyCharm 2017.3.3 hangs

Tags: python, java

There is [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), an IDE for programming Python. It's available in a [Community edition for Linux as well](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/download-thanks.html?platform=linux&code=PCC). The problem affects (at least) version 2017.3.3.

I installed it as a normal user with

```
wget https://download.jetbrains.com/python/pycharm-community-2017.3.3.tar.gz
tar -xzf pycharm-community-2017.3.3.tar.gz
mv pycharm-community-2017.3.3 pycharm
rm pycharm-community-2017.3.3.tar.gz
cd pycharm/bin
./pycharm.sh
```

The remaining installation steps are guided by a wizard:

- do not import settings
- accept license
- Darcula theme
- create a startup script
- install Markdown support
- confirm warning about granted permissions
- create a new project, create virtual environment
- wait for installation of setuptools, pip, wheels etc.
- close startup tips
- wait until indexing is done
- wait until skeletons are built
- wait until packages are scanned

So far, everything is fine.

However, even when all those steps have completed successfully, PyCharm hangs in several situations, e.g.

- when loading a project (sometimes)
- when typing code into a .py file (sometimes)
- when running the project (always)

What is the cause and how can I fix it?

I have installed the Rasbian IMG file from 2017-11-29 and performed `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` prior to the PyCharm installation.

Comment: Even am facing the same problem on windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to the Java version. In my case, the Java version is

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

The same version is also mentioned in the PyCharm about dialog.

You may not have noticed it, but PyCharm displays a message in the event log.

> IDE's Java runtime (1.8u65), which may cause instability. Update to version 1.8.0u144 or higher.

The solution is to be to update to a newer Java version. However,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

will not install a new version.

However,

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get remove oracle*
reboot
```

solved the problem and OpenJDK was installed. You should confirm that with a Java version check:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-1-deb9u1-b12)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Since then, PyCharm operated totally fine for us.

You could also download and install a Java version manually, but since we are teaching kids, we wanted to have a simple OS-supported solution.

Comment: Oracle Java 8 u161 is [available from their download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), although if you don't need Oracle for whatever reason you might as well use the Ice-T version.

Comment: it seems this solution didnt work on Windows 10 , pycharm is still slow , but why is this problem ?

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris: you run PyCharm on Windows 10 IoT on Raspberry?

Comment: No i dont use Raspberry , just my ycharm doesnt work well its slow on Windows 10 but my PC is 8gb , 500HD and an I core 5 , but its slow and freezes alot

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris: ok, just a side note: this is the wrong forum to ask such a question, because this site is Raspberry specific. I can just say PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5 runs fine on my machine on JRE 1.8.0_112. However that's not the latest version of PyCharm. Maybe such a question is on-topic on SO, such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363526/pycharm-running-wayyyy-slow